# What is considered a write against the entity group limit in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, distributed-database

According to the Datastore documentation, there is a maximum write rate to an entity group of 1 per second.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

I'd like to know if this scenario counts towards that limit as a single, or multiple queries.

There have been similar questions on Stack Overflow - but they don't seem to confirm what you *can* do.

```
const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')();

const key1 = datastore.key(['Users', 1, 'Comments']);

const comment1 = {
    userId: 1,
    commentBody: '...',
    ts: new Date(),
};

const key2 = datastore.key(['Users', 2, 'Comments']);

const comment2 = {
    userId: 2,
    commentBody: '...',
    ts: new Date(),
};

datastore.save({
    key: key1,
    data: comment1
}, (err) => {
    //
});

datastore.save({
    key: key2,
    data: comment2
}, (err) => {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your entities here, you have 2 entity groups:

1. Users/1
2. Users/2

Then you save 2 comment entities, one under each entity group. This counts as 1 write per entity-group.

Comment: I was hoping so! Thanks Dan